# Uppercase "M" at the right of window name in tmux

Tags: tmux

For some reason, occasionally, an uppercase M appears at the right side of the window name, so the window name looks like this:

```
1:bash*M
```

I'm pretty sure is because I'm pressing some combination that causes this. What is it and what does it means?

Comment: Finally someone who also felt my pain.

Comment: It also changed the stripe between panes from a nice thin line to a bright wide obnoxious thing.  Cutting this off without wiping out my context is very nice.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

From [`tmux(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1):

> ```
> m
>     Mark the current pane (see select-pane -m).
> ```

So that means you've pressed `C-b m` (or equivalent in your environment) to mark that pane.

Marking a pane is useful for certain pane operations; from the section on [`select-pane`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#select-pane):

> The marked pane is the default target for `-s` to `join-pane`, `swap-pane`
>   and `swap-window`.

To clear the mark, press `C-b M`. If you have `M` mapped to something else already, you can also use `C-b :` (to enter the `tmux` command prompt), followed by [`select-pane -M`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#select-pane) to clear the mark.

Comment: In my setup with mouse options turned on, right clicking a pane marks it.

Comment: I've overwritten `Prefix + M` in my tmux. What command can I use to unmark the pane (without enabling mouse mode)?

Comment: PS, not everyone uses `C-b` as their prefix.

Comment: You can use `C-b :` followed by `select-pane -M` to clear the mark. The original answer does mention "or equivalent", but presumably most `tmux` users are aware that `C-b` is the default prefix.

Comment: @paradroid YES! And right clicking again in the pane (not its name) unmarks it.. Houray! No more ugly M!

Answer (score 7):

The list of window flags with their explanation can be found in [`man tmux` /STATUS LINE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#STATUS_LINE), you’re looking for:

```
Symbol    Meaning
M         The window contains the marked pane.
```